# PHP code for showing current month all date's in table and previous date fields disabled

Tags: php, date, monthcalendar

Show current month all date. And the previous date fields disabled
this is my code. I write the code correctly but its showing some error how can i fix this issue.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"-"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Any idea

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++)
{
   $dates[] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) "-"  date('m') . "-" . date('Y');
}
?>
<table border='1'>

<th>Date</th>
<th>Text</th>
<?php foreach($dates as $date) {?>
<tr>

    <td>
        <?php echo $date; ?>
    </td>

     <td><input type="text"></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"-"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: `$dates[] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). "-" . date('m') . "-" . date('Y');` you are missing `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script.

Comment: How can I disabled previous date fields

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++)
{
   $dates[] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT). "-" . date('m') . "-" . date('Y');
}
?>
<table border='1'>

<th>Date</th>
<th>Text</th>
<?php foreach($dates as $date) {?>
<tr>

    <td>
        <?php echo $date; ?>
    </td>
    <?php
     if($date >= date("d-m-Y"))
     {
    ?>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
     <?php } else { ?>
     <td><input type="text" disabled></td>
     <?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah thank you it's working

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Some sort of explanation would be nice.